# using python function any() on a list of floats

Tags: python, list, any

I am trying to find whether any number from one list exists in another list. I am doing it in following way:

```
print any([20.0,0.0,19.0,1.0]) in [20.0,0.0]
```

This prints

```
False
```

Whereas it should be

```
True
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Well, that's a bit different to the usual "why is `0 == 1 or 2 or 3` true?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's not what `any` does. `any` takes an iterable of values, interprets them as booleans, and returns a boolean indicating whether any of them were `True`. At least one of `[20.0, 0.0, 19.0, 1.0]` is nonzero, which means it counts as `True`, so `any([20.0, 0.0, 19.0, 1.0])` evaluates to `True`, and your print statement is equivalent to `print True in [20.0, 0.0]`. Which is itself `False`.

To do this with `any`, use a generator expression:

```
print any(x in [20.0, 0.0] for x in [20.0, 0.0, 19.0, 1.0])
```

If you're doing this for any significant number of values, you'll get major performance improvements from using a set. `in` on a list is linear with the length of the list, while `in` on a set is constant time.

```
targets_set = set([20.0, 0.0])
print any(x in targets_set for x in [20.0, 0.0, 19.0, 1.0])
```

Answer (score 6):

[`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) returns `True` if any item in the iterable is true. (non-zero number is true).

```
>>> any([20.0,0.0,19.0,1.0])
True
```

`any([20.0,0.0,19.0,1.0]) in [20.0,0.0]` is like `True in [20.0, 0.0]`.

To get what you want, try following (using generator expression).

```
>>> any(n in [20.0, 0.0] for n in [20.0, 0.0, 19.0, 1.0])
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also create difference between two sets and check if there is any element in result set

```
intersection = set([20.0,0.0,19.0,1.0]) & set([20.0,0.0])
print (len(intersection) > 0)
```

`set([20.0,0.0,19.0,1.0]) & set([20.0,0.0])` creates new set `set([0.0, 20.0])` which contains elements which are in both left and right set
and `len(intersection) > 0` returns `True` if there is at least one element in iterable (in this case set)

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, that returns `True` iff there is at least one element in the left hand set that isn't in the right hand set. The OP asked for a way to tell whether there is at least one element in the left hand set that is in the right hand set.

Comment: `any` isn't true if "there is at least one element" - it is true if there is at least one *truthy* element; try `any({0})`. You want `bool(...)`, which *is* true if and only if the set is non-empty. But even then, this won't actually do what the OP wants: the whole expression is true if there is at least one element in the first set that *isn't* in the second. `bool({1} - {0})` is true but it should be false; `bool({1,2} - {1,2,3})` is false when it should be true.

Comment: Yup, did not read well what is required, and made incorrect statement about any func. For example this will return false negative print any([0.0]). Thanks for point me out my answer is incorrect. I have changed it, I hope its ok now

Comment: The set intersection method should work - although I'd just call `bool(intersection)` rather than bother looking up the length. It doesn't short-circuit, unlike `any`, but the set implementation is quite fast so I hesitate to say that it would be slower without profiling.

Comment: Yup, just wanted to provide different approach to the problem and in hurry made stupid mistake with any. I gave upvote for both other answers